# Using natural deduction to prove P ∧ ¬Q ∧ (R → S), ¬(P → S) ⊢ R → Q

Tags: logic, proof-verification, propositional-calculus, natural-deduction

I would like to prove:

$1. \qquad P ∧ ¬Q  ∧ R → S \qquad (Premise)$

$2. \qquad ¬(P → S) \qquad (Premise)$

$ ...$

$3. \qquad  R → Q \qquad$

with access to these rules ([http://imgur.com/kPZEYtG](https://imgur.com/kPZEYtG))
However I am not sure how to proceed after this step:

[image]

---

As a side note does anyone know how to enter $P ∧ ¬Q ∧ R → S, ¬(P → S) ⊢ R → Q$ into this great [online natural deduction with steps tool](http://teachinglogic.liglab.fr/DN/index.php) I am not sure how to enter premises.

Comment: The question appears to be wrong because $(¬Q \land R)$ and $(R \rightarrow Q)$ is a contradiction

Comment: Is the first premise supposed to say $ P ∧ ¬Q  ∧ R \rightarrow S$?

Comment: sorry fixed @Shanye2020

Comment: yes @browngreen

Comment: Are you allowed to use deduction theorem? You can prove (P & -Q & R => S) => ((-(P=>S))=>(R=>Q)) with the tool.

Comment: @GeorgyDunaev 
I am using Jape and have access to these rules http://imgur.com/kPZEYtG

Comment: Could you put some parenthesis around your first premise so I don't have to guess what you mean please?

Comment: @GeorgyDunaev Deduction theorem is a rule of inference of natural deduction.

Comment: @DanielV there is no parenthesis in the question https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0FIt.png is how is it given

Comment: So you don't even know the way the parenthesis should be?  The first step to solving a problem is understanding the question, and I strongly doubt all you have access to is that little graphic, something somewhere probably clarifies it for you.  Anyway, guessing the meaning, you probably want something like $R \vdash S \vdash P \to S \vdash \bot \vdash Q$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a straightforward proof:

[image]

Comment: What tool is that?

Comment: It's called Fitch, it comes with the book Language, Proof, and Logic.

Answer (score 0):

Lets prove it by contradiction.

We will try to make the Premises as True and Conclusion as False. (If we are not able to do this, then the inference is True)

To make the conclusion R→Q false, we must take R as True and Q as False (no other way we can make it false).

Considering these values of R and Q let us try to make the premises as True.

Premise 1: P ^ -Q ^ R→S

We have to take R as True and Q as false.
So, P ^ -Q (True) ^ R (True)→S

This expression can be made True only by putting P as True and S as True. If any of these are False, Premise 1 becomes False.

Premise 2: -(P→S)

We have already taken P as True and S as True.
So Premise 2 becomes False.

Therefore there is no such case when the Premises are True and Conclusion is False.

Hence the Inference is True. Proved.

Hope it helped.